# Smart Contract inheriting a contract to supply part of Interface

Tags: solidity

Given a smart contract setup where there is an Interface object that defines multiple different functions that a new contract wishes to adhere to, and it wants to inherit some functionality to define some of that logic, I expected a structure like this to work:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

interface A {
    function foo() external returns (uint256);
    function bar() external returns (uint256);
}

contract B {
    function foo() public returns (uint256) {
        return 1;
    }
}

contract MyContract is A, B {
    function bar() public returns (uint256) {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

The Solidity compiler fails to compile this, giving the error "TypeError: Derived contract must override function "foo". Two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types."

It finds the `foo` reference in both the `A` interface and the `B` contract definition and seems to be unable to merge them, even though `A` is an interface, and its definition of `foo` is just a definition, not an implementation.

The only way I've found around this is to add a function to `MyContract` like

```
function foo() public override(A, B) returns (uint256) {
    return B.foo();
}
```

Is this a bug in the compiler (it's not ignoring function definitions that aren't implemented), or is there a more elegant way to combine logic like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through past issue requests on the Solidity GitHub, it appears this situation falls into the same space as [this request](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/8970), and the answer is the Solidity compiler forces that additional declaration on the child contract as a design choice; forcing the developer to indicate they are aware that there are two methods with the same name, and to explicitly declare they're not just named the same, but are functionally/conceptually the same.

The other option, if the developer has control of the definition of `B`, is to do:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

interface A {
    function foo() external returns (uint256);
    function bar() external returns (uint256);
}

abstract contract B is A {
    function foo() public returns (uint256) {
        return 1;
    }
}

contract MyContract is B {
    function bar() public override returns (uint256) {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Namely, change `B` to not be a Contract but an Abstract Contract, explicitly defining it as a partial implementation of interface `A`, and have `MyContract` only inherit from `B`.